# Testing the equality of two regression coefficients from same data but different frequency

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, independence

I am using tick data of implied volatility and their underlying asset price and extract two data sets of hourly frequency and daily frequency. The two data sets are formed from the same tick data. I run OLS regression for each data set:
$$Y_{t,hourly} = \beta_1 X_{hourly} + \epsilon_t,$$
$$Y_{t,daily} = \beta_2 X_{daily} + \epsilon_t.$$
$Y$ is change in implied volatility and $X$ is log return of the underlying asset.
Please suggest how to test $H_0: \beta_1=\beta_2$.

The data is fundamentally dependent, so the $Z$ test
$$
Z = \frac{\beta_1 - \beta_2}{\sqrt{{SE_1^2 +SE_2^2}}} 
$$
cannot be used, as it assumes data to be independent. $SE_j$ is the standard error of the respective coefficient.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what process it is that makes the two data sets dependent. Is the hourly data contained inside the daily data? Are $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ fitted parameters for different sampling methods from the *same* stream of data or for two *different* streams of data? What are you trying to achieve in comparing $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$?

Comment: Have you considered SUR? Or are your SEs too complicated for that be feasible?

Comment: Isn't it a mathematical necessity that $\beta_1=\beta_2$? That would follow from the impressions you leave that each of these datasets is a differenced value of a common time series, only with different lags.  I guess I'm assuming there's no daily seasonal component to either series, which leaves me wondering what assumptions we *should* be making.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough data to assess daily vs. hourly rates, I am going to assume you have enough data to split the data in half.  Because linear regression assumes a constant slope (which I assume you believe to be true), then you should obtain similar slopes for different regions of the line (top or bottom) or for different steps along the line.  Of course, this introduces another source of chance variability, but as a "quick" solution, this may be reasonable.

Step 1: break the data into two sets: even days and odd days
Step 2: calculate the regression coefficients for hour from one set & day from the other
Step 3: use the 2nd formula you've presented above

This will (1) introduce more variability because you are using less data to make your inferences, but (2) it will break the inter-dependency violation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that but the model shows some dependency on data. For one set, I get the coefficients equal at 5% level, but if I swap the data sets, they are not. Can it be concluded that they are not equal?

Comment: let me make sure I understand...if you run the hour model with data_set_1 and the day model with data_set_2, you get one result, and if you switch the data sets, you get a different result (based on the p-value dichotomy)...¿correct?

Comment: one other thing...¿what would the units of the slope coefficient be?

Comment: Thanks again for reply. Yes, you got it right. I use log difference for both returns and implied volatility, so the slope will have no units.

Comment: For the inconsistent findings, my suggestion would be to go the "voice of the crowd" method...try other random-half splits (I'd recommend by whole days).  See how often the test statistics you calculate agree and disagree.  Then, the overall finding should suggest a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: Hi: You can add the two equations and estimate that (with the sum as response ) which means that $\beta_1$ should equal $\beta_2$ in the  hourly + day case. For that test, you can use an F-test where you estimate restricted model and unrestricted model and subtract the sums of squares. I forget the exact formula but it's straightforward.

Comment: I think above won't work because you don't have 1 hourly data point and 1 daily data point so there isn't a one to relation so it's not additive. . But maybe you can create an average hourly observation so that you create a one to one relation ?  If this isn't possible, then forget my previous comment and  my apologies for noise.